# function which takes a general array type

Tags: c++

I want to make a function which takes an array-like type (eg. std::vector, std::array, C array, ...etc). The body of my function only requires that the argument have a subscript operator [] which returns a specific type.
For example, suppose I want to write following functions, Is there a way to write the code only once rather than repeating the same code three times?

```
AddOne(std::array<double> &array, int size){
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
  array[i] += 1;
}
AddOne(std::vector<double> &array, int size){
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
  array[i] += 1;
}
AddOne(double *array, int size){
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
  array[i] += 1;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: create template

Answer (score 3):

Yep, this is what templates are for:

```
template<typename T>
AddOne(T &array, int size){
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    array[i] += 1;
  }
}
```

Note that you don't need to specify explicitly that the type needs to have an `[]` operator. This will be checked at every point where the template is being used (which can result in the unreadable compile errors that C++ is notorious for).

---

A more idiomatic approach would be to pass a pair of iterators:

```
template<typename T>
AddOne(T begin, T end) {
  for (; begin != end; begin++) {
    (*begin) += 1;
  }
}
```

For e.g. `std::vector`, you'd call `AddOne(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end())`. For raw arrays, you'd just pass pointers, like `AddOne(my_array, my_array + size)`.